# An adjective relating to the circus?

Tags: description, language, phrasing

I'm looking for an adjective which essentially means "of or relating to the circus." My context is:

> As they stood in the doorway, taking in the **circus-like** activities around them...

But "circus-like" is garbage, can anyone suggest a good adjective to use in its place? Alternatively, I could replace the entire described noun ("circus-like activities") with something better. I suppose I could just called it a "circus" directly, which will probably be my fall back.

I'm not entirely oppose to making up words, but it would need to be easily comprehensible to the reader. I was thinking something like "circusian" or "circusean".

Comment: Since your question is one of "word choice and usage", it *might* get a better answer at [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).  (I am not certain about whether that means you should flag it for moderator attention or some other action should be taken.)  "circus atmosphere" *might* substitute for "circus-like activities", though it describes general environment rather than the hustle and bustle of a circus.

Comment: Thanks, and noted. I've got a satisfactory answer from Craig, but in the future I'll pose these questions to the suggested site.

Comment: Straight-ahead word choice questions are clearly [off-topic](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/a/675/26), here, but questions that deal with how to choose the right word are okay. Since the answer covers that last, I think we can give this question the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as belonging on English.SE. It cannot be move, but gives a wrong impression of what may be asked her, so I would prefer to see it deleted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on EnglishLanguage&Usage.SE

Comment: I'm fine with closing it, I'll use English.SE for this in the future. Thanks for the consideration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Circensian" is a word, which means "of or relating to the Circus in ancient Rome", so you could potentially consider using that, but it likely doesn't really fit.

Since this is Writers.SE, however, I would fall back to Stephen King's comment that  “The road to hell is paved with adjectives.” Why not simply describe the activities that are occuring around them? "circus-activities" is so incredibly broad that it's boring and meangingless. It's difficult to say really without knowing the full context of the sentence, but I suspect that describing the action would be a better option. There are jugglers, freaks, unicyclists, clowns, ring masters, men of strength, bearded ladies ... use the imagination, and make your text richer through showing.

Comment: Thanks, I think "circensian" will do fine. In this particular instance, the adjective reiterates what has already been "shown". But I get your point, and will keep it in mind. Thanks!